# Best search method for keyword search

Tags: elasticsearch

On my document I have the following text indexed as a keyword

`80TL00ABM/256GB SSD`

Now, what is the best way to search for this?

I have tried with a [Match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and also with [Match phrase prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) but both requires I search for the whole word, and not just `80TL00ABM`

Also if I dont index it as a keyword, then I cant search for it with the whole string, properly because of the `/`

`Indexed with:
type: keyword
normalizer: char_filter: [], filter: [lowercase]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { "FIELD" : "80tl00abm/256gb ssd" } 
  }
}
```

The match query works with text field. For keyword field is better use term query. Note that the string searched is lowercased, because you have used a normalizer that lowercase the keyword

Comment: Just note that the field has a normalizer with a `lowercase` token filter, so the string should be all lowercase, too, i.e. there's no equivalent such as search-time analyzers for keyword fields.

Comment: @Val you're right. I haven't seen the normalizer in the question

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make use of [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/multi-fields.html). This allows you to index the same field twice, with different index-time analyzers that can give you flexibility when doing searches. For example:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "mytype": {
      "properties": {
        "myfield": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "analyzed": {
                "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This indexes "myfield" twice, once as a keyword for exact matches using a term query, and once as text, using the match query.

This term query will operate on the keyword field:

```
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "myfield": "80TL00ABM/256GB SSD"
        }
    }
}
```

This match query will operate on the analyzed field. Note the difference in the field name used to perform the search:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "myfield.analyzed": "80TL00ABM"
        }
    }
}
```

As noted in other answers, be aware of the lowercase filters you use, so that you can provide the correct case when using the term query.